# set terminate function c++

Tags: c++, terminate

How can I save current function which is used by set_terminate and set new function in it?
NOTE: I want to use pointers on function. I tried somenthing like this so far, but I'm now confused and don't know what to do:

How to send a pointer to a function, and its functionality is to terminate the current program and can I save current pointer on function that is used by set_terminate and how?

```cpp
typedef void (*PF) ();
void empty() {
    cout << "empty" << endl;
    exit(-1);
}

int main() {

    PF set_terminate(PF pf);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does "used by set_terminate" mean? `set_terminate` is just a declaration in `main()`. Declarations don't "use" anything. They're just declarations. And declarations like that inside functions is generally considered to be confusing, and not the best programming practice.

Comment: could you rephrase your question, please? I think you are asking: how to send a pointer to a function, and its functionality is to terminate the current program, is this correct?

Comment: @Sam There's a [function in the Standard Library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/set_terminate).

Comment: Yes, it is my problem and also can I save current pointer on function that is used by set_terminate?

Comment: Something like this: `PF oldfunc = set_terminate(newfunc);`. Although you can use the `std::terminate_handler` type instead of defining your own `PF`.

Comment: I think the question is clear enough. The OP's attempt at code isn't very close, but I guess that's why they're asking.

Comment: @AdrianMole -- I agree. It's quite clear what the question is, and the close votes clearly demonstrate why beginners are reluctant to ask questions.